# How do I find the thermal effect of this reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, heat

I have graphite turning into diamond.I need to find the thermal effect of this reaction.How would one write that?I'm not sure how to proceed here.The teacher told us to use oxygen?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by "thermal effect"?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the difference between the enthalpies of formation. Not sure why you'd need oxygen, unless there's something I'm missing.